# Зачем нужен оператор continue в Python?

Tags: python, операторы

Неужели только для того, чтобы пропустить цифру?

```
count = 1

while True:
    count += 1
    if count == 504:
        continue
    if count > 520:
        break
    print (count)
```

Comment: Он нужен для того, чтобы перейти к следующей итерации цикла не доходя до конца тела цикла.

Comment: Очень прошу, по-проще можете обьяснить?

Comment: После того, как выполнится continue, цикл перейдет в начало итерации. То есть в вашем случае если выполнится первый блок if, то второй даже не будет проверяться и не сработает print.

Comment: Скажите кто Вы по специальности. Ну к примеру повару я бы обьяснил так. Есть задача, сжарить 520 котлет - это весь цыкл от первой итерации и до последней. Одна котлета = одна итерация. Процесс от забора куска фарша и до полной прожарки = тело цикла, то есть список всего что нужно сделать для сжарки одной котлеты. И вот жарите Вы 504-ю котлету. И вдруг переворачивая на другую сторону видите "continue". Бросаете недожареную 504-ю колету на тарелку к остальным и беретесь жарить 505-ю.  То есть Вы не бросили всю задачу и не свалили с ресторана домой после 504-й, а продолжили дальше выполнять цикл.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров ааа, получается это используется чтобы дать числу исключение? что вот ты, 504, можешь не выполнять все, что стоит ниже Continue?

Comment: @V.March то есть я даю исключение и освобождаю 504-е число от заданий?

Comment: @ЭдуардВан Вы правильно мыслите. Когда проверка покажет что count == 504, то следующей проверки `if count > 520`и `print (count)` уже не будет, а сразу начнется новый виток цикла.  В консоли это будет выглядеть так: ... 502, 503, 505, 506 ....

Comment: @но если я поставлю print() до continue то это значение прочитается? Допустим:~~~ while true
x=1
y=1
x+=1
y+=1 
print(x,y)
 if y==504
      continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор `continue` в Python создан для того, чтобы прервать текущую итерацию цикла. Например:

```py
for i in range(10):
    if i in [1, 5 , 6]:
        continue
    print(i, end=" ")
```

Для данного примера вывод будет такой: 
`0 2 3 4 7 8 9`